# Need assistance with getting my shiny app code to sum rainfall figures for a month prior to a selected date

Tags: r, shiny

I have written a shiny app in Rstudio that I want to develop in order to analyse dairy production figures. I have a drop down menu in the app that allows me to select a date, after which various figures are produced for the specific date selected. I want to add a new column (in the app, not the original data set) that outputs the "total Rain for the Month". it is important that the code only sums the values in the "Rain" column in the dataset for the month of the selected date, but only from the beginning of the month until the date selected (i.e., for the date 2023-06-19, only rain from 2021-06-01 to 2021-06-19 must be summed). My code currently fails to produce the new column in the shiny app, so I am not entirely sure where the issue is exactly, but I am hoping that someone here will have some good suggestions.

Below is a sample of the larger dataset that I am working with:

```
d <- structure(list(date = c(
  "2020-08-01", "2020-08-02", "2020-08-03",
  "2020-08-04", "2020-08-05", "2020-08-06", "2020-08-07"
), Milk.sold = c(
  17396L,
  17715L, 18071L, 17950L, 17749L, 17821L, 17749L
), Rations = c(
  43L,
  27L, 48L, 55L, 32L, 45L, 48L
), Tot.milk = c(
  17439L, 17742L, 18119L,
  18005L, 17781L, 17866L, 17797L
), No.cows = c(
  1142L, 1158L, 1166L,
  1159L, 1166L, 1178L, 1187L
), Liters.cow = c(
  15.3, 15.3, 15.5,
  15.5, 15.2, 15.2, 15
), Rain = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 9, 2.5), Weighted.Growth = c(
  0,
  0, 0, 12.2, 0, 0, 0
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "1",
  "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"
))
```

So, for this data, if I selected the date 2020-08-07, I would expected (if the app and code is correct) to have the column "Total Rain for the Month" in the app to output 23.5 (the sum of 12, 9 and 2.5).

Here is my current code at the time of writing this post:

```
# Define the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Glen Dye Dashboard"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateInput("selected_date", "Select a Date:", value = as.Date("2021-01-12"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h3("Daily Figures"),
      tableOutput("selected_data")
    )
  )
)


# Define the server
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Render the selected data table
  output$selected_data <- renderTable({
    selected_date <- as.Date(input$selected_date)  # Convert selected date to Date format
    
    # Extract the year and month from the selected date
    selected_year <- lubridate::year(selected_date)
    selected_month <- lubridate::month(selected_date)
    
    # Filter the data for the selected month and up to the selected date
    filtered_data <- d %>% 
      filter(lubridate::year(as.Date(date)) == selected_year,
             lubridate::month(as.Date(date)) == selected_month,
             as.Date(date) <= selected_date)
    
    # Calculate the total rain for the selected month
    total_rain <- sum(filtered_data$Rain)
    
    # Create the new column "Total Rain for the Month"
    selected_data <- data.frame(filtered_data, "Total Rain for the Month" = total_rain)
    
    # Rename the column names
    colnames(selected_data) <- c("Milk sold", "Rations", "Total Milk", "Cows in milk", 
                                 "Liters/Cow", "Rain", "Weighted Growth", "Pasture Utilized",
                                 "Total Rain for the Month")  # Corrected column name
    
    selected_data
  })
  
  # Automatically update the table when a date is selected
  observeEvent(input$selected_date, {
    output$selected_data <- renderTable({
      selected_date <- input$selected_date
      selected_data <- d[d$date == selected_date, c("Milk.sold", "Rations", "Tot.milk", "No.cows", "Liters.cow", "Rain", "Weighted.Growth","Pasture.utilized")]
      colnames(selected_data) <- c("Milk sold", "Rations", "Total Milk", "Cows in milk", "Liters/Cow", "Rain","Weighted Growth","Pasture Utilized")
      selected_data
    })
  })
}

# Run the Shiny app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option to achieve your desired result. Note that there is no need for an `observeEvent` to update your table when the user selects a date. `renderTable()` will already take care of that.

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Glen Dye Dashboard"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateInput("selected_date", "Select a Date:",
        value = as.Date("2020-08-07"),
        min = min(as.Date(d$date)), max = max(as.Date(d$date))
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h3("Daily Figures"),
      tableOutput("selected_data")
    )
  )
)

# Define the server
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$selected_data <- renderTable({
    selected_date <- as.Date(input$selected_date)

    filtered_data <- d %>%
      filter(
        as.Date(date) >= floor_date(selected_date, "month"),
        as.Date(date) <= selected_date
      ) %>%
      mutate(total_rain = sum(Rain)) %>%
      filter(as.Date(date) == selected_date) |>
      select(-date)

    colnames(filtered_data) <- c(
      "Milk sold", "Rations", "Total Milk", "Cows in milk",
      "Liters/Cow", "Rain", "Weighted Growth",
      "Total Rain for the Month"
    )

    filtered_data
  })
}

# Run the Shiny app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4271
```

[image]